# How come I can filter on a column that I have already dropped in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

When I drop a column from a dataframe in spark, I expect that I can no longer use that column.

However, it turns out that I can in this example:

```
schema=['a','b']
data = [[1,2],[3,4],[1,1]]
sparkSession.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema).drop('a').filter(func.col('a')!=func.col('b')).toPandas()
```

This returns the column b with rows containing 2 and 4. I expected that it would crash because it didn't have column 'a' available.

How can I drop a column and prevent it being used? Where is this behavior documented?

Comment: The same behaviour happens if I select a subset of the columns. The only way I have found to stop this behaviour is to overwrite column b.

Comment: It's a known issue in spark, look here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30421

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/27128

Comment: thanks. It looks like this is a known issue which they won't fix because some workflows depend on this. It seems obviously a bug to me. Hmm.